# Absolute positioned element in responsive design trouble

Tags: wordpress, position, absolute

This is the wordpress site I'm working on.

http://northbroad.2one5dev.com/

Basically, the 6 labels, 1-6, will trigger a new div to appear when you mouse over them.

The problem is, the map image is set for responsive design, where its width is defined by percent, so it scales based on browser size. But the hotspots I have are absolute positioned based on "top" and "left", which mean they lose their correct spot based on browser size that are different than mines.

Is there any way to make this work so that the hotspots will scale and follow the background image regardless of screen width?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I tried wrapping all the hotspot divs as a child of the parent div that contains the map image of the background, but that still doesnt solve the issue, because the left/top positioning are fixed. I'm nt really sure how to make this work without making the map image having a defined width/height.

Answer (score 0):

Another work around for hotspots in a fluid design is to make a responsive static image with links in Edge Animate. The hotspots (or layers that act as hotspots) are then totally responsive. The downside being that a 50kb image will be about 120kb's when output from Edge. Having said that its a pretty quick work around.